# Showing progress towards badges

Tags: feature-request, badges

As a feature, show how close/far someone is to getting a badge that has more than one part. I.e. for convention, show how many posts the user has with a score above 2 in meta (if its less than 10), or for Copy Editor, how many edits they have made.

Does not seem like a big deal to add, but it would also answer question like "does this count as an edit?" really easily for the user (they could just do it and find out).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The lack of information describing your exact progress towards badges has been indicated by Jeff and/or the other developers to be an intentional design choice <sup>[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-pundit-etc-badge-progress/34440#34440), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/so-badge-progress-report/3340#3340)</sup> so anything of this nature is unlikely to be implemented

However, if you look at the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/), you will find quite a few queries that will help estimate progress (do remember the data explorer isn't live data and so won't be fully up to date).

Comment: Never knew about that before...

Comment: @soandos I guess you mean the Data Explorer? It's pretty handy, but as mentioned, do pay attention to the date of update on the front page - it is only updated every month or so.

Comment: +1, never knew about Data Explorer either.  Already wrote a few queries, awesome resource.

Answer (score 2):

I can see this being a fun.

But I see a big gotcha here.  I CAN see this bringing in a WHOLE boatload of support calls. "IT'S NOT UPDATING" "WHERE DID MY POST CREDIT GO??"

I propose a different solution:  Pretty graphs and timelines.  Still gives people a sense of accomplishment and a need to motivate.  At the same time, reporting services like these are a lot easier to support.

Comment: I thought mine would be easier to implement, but what do you want graph?

Comment: Timelines, the cool graphics that people are doing over at API/APPS.  I guess, then again, people are already doing that, it's just not easily discoverable. Can be solved with a link in the profile.