# Why is there no way to look at progress towards different badges?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Does anyone know why there is no ability to view progress/statistics towards particular badges or just have the overall ability to look at progress for accounts?  I feel like this would be very helpful.

I found the following post mentioning that this behavior is by design, but I fail to see why that decision was made.  I'm not criticizing, I am genuinely curious.

[Showing progress towards badges](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2999/showing-progress-towards-badges)

Comment: Any particular badges you wonder about? There's this little helper: http://stackapps.com/questions/2982/stinkingbadges-track-your-progress-towards-long-term-badges

Comment: Yes, as an example, the Civic Duty badge (Vote 300 or more times).

Comment: You should be able to check your progress on Civic Duty by hovering over the progress bar in the review section: http://i.imgur.com/yHjYp9A.png

Comment: Ah very cool, I had no idea about that feature!

Comment: Also on your profile page on the summary tab in the lower right is a section on Votes Cast.